# how to configure no proxy in settings.xml in maven?

Tags: java, xml, apache, maven

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<proxies>
<proxy>
  <id>myproxy</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <host>10.51.0.90</host>
  <port>8181</port>
</proxy>
</proxies>
</settings>
```

i dont want to use any proxy .. how to configure and what are the changes to be done in this xml file

Comment: simply remove the `proxy` section

Comment: <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
</settings>

Comment: comment that code between <proxy> to </proxy>

Comment: it is saying port must be integer

Comment: If you have such issues, download fresh maven check it config file by default there is no proxy enable. Just copy that code. BTW, You should comment whole code starting from <proxy> to </proxy>

Answer (score 2):

```
<proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username></username>
      <password></password>
      <host>proxies.proxy.host</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
```

Comment: maybe cite the source: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Answer (score 0):

keep the xml file as is; just delete the host address and port. like below

```
<host></host><port></port>
```

Comment: its saying port must be an integer

Comment: try this. hope this will work 

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<proxies>
<proxy>
  <id>myproxy</id>
  <active>false</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <host>10.51.0.90</host>
  <port>8181</port>
</proxy>
<nonProxyHosts>localhost,127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
</proxies>
</settings>

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off proxy for Maven by changing true to false:

```
<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>false</active>
</proxy>
```